# dm-crypt plain on top of lvm with /boot on usb

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption, lvm

Just as a preface, due to the specificity of my question, I did not find a thread that applies to my question. With that, I'll get started.

Here are main points of what I'm trying to do:

- Full disk encryption (plain dm-crypt)
- Separate /, /var, /home, and swap partitions using LVM
- /boot partition on USB drive using a keyscript

First, I wrote random bits to the drive-to-be-encrypted. Then, I created the dm-crypt device mapping. Here's my command:

```
cryptsetup open --type plain /dev/sda  sda_crypt --hash sha512 --cipher serpent-xts-plain64:sha512 --key-file tempkeyfile.bin --key-size 512
```

The tempkeyfile.bin is a temporary placement in RAM of the keyfile that will be created for boot.

Now, I have no problem (that I can see) creating the physical volume, volume group, and logical volumes. I then create a /boot partition on the USB drive (1G partition just to be safe) as ext2.

There's more to this setup, but hopefully that gives you an idea of what I'm attempting to do. Onward, I get everything setup and then go to ubiquity to install and it hangs at "Saving installed packages" which I did find a bug for [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/875343). It seems like it has something to do with creating the separate /var partition, but unsure at this time.

Any assistance on this matter would be more than greatly appreciated. I understand the complexity of this task and further understand that there are other options, though I want several things that the default installer doesn't seem to provide (sha512 hashed serpent cipher, for one). I'm not sure what system items will be needed and/or further explanations, so if you could point me in the right direction, I'll provide what I can.

I tried this using 15.10 and 14.04.3. Same results.